# Network manager connection to openvpn server configured with Ubuntu 23.10 tutorial

Tags: networking, network-manager, openvpn

I've completed the setup of a server using the Ubuntu tutorial here:
https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/service-openvpn

After configuring the `client.conf` file as described, with the `ca.crt`, `myclient1.crt`, `myclient1.key`, `ta.key` files, the server works as expected when doing `sudo systemctl start openvpn@client`.

My question is how to do the same configuration using the network manager so that nm-openvpn can connect. There are boxes to enter all the files, except for the `ta.key` file.  I attempted to enter the `ta.key` file in the advanced tab called "TSL Authentication", under the "TSL-Auth" mode dropdown, yet I continue to see the error message:

`Oct 25 22:33:41 esperanza nm-openvpn[45394]: Cannot load private key file /home/path/to/my/ta.key`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key direction is set to "None" by default, but it must be "1" for the client.

[image: advanced properties]